# Java: Getting a font with a specific height in pixels

Tags: java, fonts, graphics2d, fontmetrics

It’s easy to determine the rendered height of a font using `FontMetrics`, but what about the other way around? How can I obtain a font that will fit into a specific height in pixels?

> "Give me `Verdana` in a size that is 30 pixels high from ascender to descender."

How do I ask Java for this?

Comment: just curious - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to optimize a text layout to make best use of the available display size

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's a "direct" way to find a font by height; only an indirect way... by looping through the sizes, and testing the height of each is <= required height.

If you're doing this once, just loop through them... if you've doing it "on the fly" then do a binary search, it'll be quicker.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is a very old question, but someone might still find it:

[The font height in Java (and many other places) is given in "typographic points", which are defined as roughly 1/72nd of an inch.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#getSize())

To calculate the points needed for a certain pixel height, you should be able to use the following:

```
double fontSize= 72.0 * pixelSize / Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
```

I haven't tested this extensively yet, but it seems to work for the monitors that I've used. I'll report back if I ever find a case where it doesn't work.

For the standard system fonts I've used this with, this sets the height of a capital letter (i.e. the ascent) to the provided pixel size. If you need to set the ascent+descent to the pixel size, you can correct the value using the [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html):

```
FontMetrics m= g.getFontMetrics(font); // g is your current Graphics object
double totalSize= fontSize * (m.getAscent() + m.getDescent()) / m.getAscent();
```

Of course, the actual pixel-height of some specific letters will depend on the letter and the font used, so if you want to make sure that your "H" is some exact number of pixels tall, you might still want to use the trial-and-error methods mentioned in the other answers. Just keep in mind that if you use these methods to get the size for each specific text you want to display (as @Bob suggested), you might end up with a random font-size-mess on your screen where a text like "ace" will have much bigger letters than "Tag". To avoid this, I would pick one specific letter or letter sequence ("T" or "Tg" or something) and fix that one to your pixel height once and then use the font size you get from that everywhere.

Comment: thanks for clarifying this... I just checked and a font of size 18f appears to be about 1/4" on my 30" monitor run from the docking port... and also appears 1/4" when I undock my laptop and use its much smaller screen... a revelation!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of a way to get a font by its actual height in pixels. It depends on the context it's used in so there's probably no shorter way than to sample for the best match. It should be pretty quick to look for sizes up or down from the designed height. Here's an example method that does that:

```
public Font getFont(String name, int style, int height) {
    int size = height;
    Boolean up = null;
    while (true) {
        Font font = new Font(name, style, size);
        int testHeight = getFontMetrics(font).getHeight();
        if (testHeight < height && up != Boolean.FALSE) {
            size++;
            up = Boolean.TRUE;
        } else if (testHeight > height && up != Boolean.TRUE) {
            size--;
            up = Boolean.FALSE;
        } else {
            return font;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

WhiteFang34's  code is useful in combination with the following method that returns the actual height of a specific string. It might be a bit slow for real-time rendering, especially for large fonts/strings and I'm sure it can be further optimised, but for now it meets my own needs and is fast enough to run in a back-end process.

```
/*
 * getFontRenderedHeight
 * *************************************************************************
 * Summary: Font metrics do not give an accurate measurement of the rendered
 * font height for certain strings because the space between the ascender
 * limit and baseline is not always fully used and descenders may not be
 * present. for example the strings '0' 'a' 'f' and 'j' are all different
 * heights from top to bottom but the metrics returned are always the same.
 * If you want to place text that exactly fills a specific height, you need
 * to work out what the exact height is for the specific string. This method
 * achieves that by rendering the text and then scanning the top and bottom
 * rows until the real height of the string is found.
 */
/**
 * Calculate the actual height of rendered text for a specific string more
 * accurately than metrics when ascenders and descenders may not be present
 * <p>
 * Note: this method is probably not very efficient for repeated measurement
 * of large strings and large font sizes but it works quite effectively for
 * short strings. Consider measuring a subset of your string value. Also
 * beware of measuring symbols such as '-' and '.' the results may be
 * unexpected!
 * 
 * @param string
 *            The text to measure. You might be able to speed this process
 *            up by only measuring a single character or subset of your
 *            string i.e if you know your string ONLY contains numbers and
 *            all the numbers in the font are the same height, just pass in
 *            a single digit rather than the whole numeric string.
 * @param font
 *            The font being used. Obviously the size of the font affects
 *            the result
 * @param targetGraphicsContext
 *            The graphics context the text will actually be rendered in.
 *            This is passed in so the rendering options for anti-aliasing
 *            can be matched.
 * @return Integer - the exact actual height of the text.
 * @author Robert Heritage [mrheritage@gmail.com]
 */
public Integer getFontRenderedHeight(String string, Font font, Graphics2D targetGraphicsContext) {
    BufferedImage image;
    Graphics2D g;
    Color textColour = Color.white;

    // In the first instance; use a temporary BufferedImage object to render
    // the text and get the font metrics.
    image = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = image.createGraphics();
    FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
    Rectangle2D rect = metrics.getStringBounds(string, g);

    // now set up the buffered Image with a canvas size slightly larger than
    // the font metrics - this guarantees that there is at least one row of
    // black pixels at the top and the bottom
    image = new BufferedImage((int) rect.getWidth() + 1, (int) metrics.getHeight() + 2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = image.createGraphics();

    // take the rendering hints from the target graphics context to ensure
    // the results are accurate.
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, targetGraphicsContext.getRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING));
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, targetGraphicsContext.getRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING));

    g.setColor(textColour);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawString(string, 0, image.getHeight());

    // scan the bottom row - descenders will be cropped initially, so the
    // text will need to be moved up (down in the co-ordinates system) to
    // fit it in the canvas if it contains any. This may need to be done a
    // few times until there is a row of black pixels at the bottom.
    boolean foundBottom, foundTop = false;
    int offset = 0;
    do {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        g.setColor(textColour);
        g.drawString(string, 0, image.getHeight() - offset);

        foundBottom = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            if (image.getRGB(x, image.getHeight() - 1) != Color.BLACK.getRGB()) {
                foundBottom = false;
            }
        }
        offset++;
    } while (!foundBottom);

    System.out.println(image.getHeight());

    // Scan the top of the image downwards one line at a time until it
    // contains a non-black pixel. This loop uses the break statement to
    // stop the while loop as soon as a non-black pixel is found, this
    // avoids the need to scan the rest of the line
    int y = 0;
    do {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            if (image.getRGB(x, y) != Color.BLACK.getRGB()) {
                foundTop = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        y++;
    } while (!foundTop);

    return image.getHeight() - y;
}
```